# Jquery datepicker cloning issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The problem is here i can't add datepick(); functionality to newly created items.

Everythig works fine except that.

The first elements which named as date1 and datep1 are has datepick and works so good.

I got the plugin there: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html What is wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../../includes/my_app/js/datepick/humanity.datepick.css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../includes/my_app/js/datepick/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../includes/my_app/js/datepick/jquery.datepick-tr.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../../includes/my_app/js/datepick/ui-ui-lightness.datepick.css" /> 
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#date1').datepick({
                    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    yearRange: '1800:2053'
                });
            });
            $(function() {
                $('#datep1').datepick({
                    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    yearRange: '1800:2053'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="stad_alt" id="myForm">
            <h1></h1>

            <div id="first">
                Please Select:
                <select name="myoption">
        <option value="1">First Option</option> 
                </select><br /><br /></div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="alternate">
                    Name 1: <input type="text" name="the_name1" id="name1" class="textbox" />
                    From :<input type="text" id="date1" name="from1" class="textbox" />
                    To :<input type="text" id="datep1" name="to1" class="textbox" />
                        Photo: <input type="file" id="photo1" name="photo1" class="textbox" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="button" id="add" value="Add New" />
                <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete This" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                var num = 1; //default 1 
                if (num == 1)
                    $('#delete').prop('disabled','disabled');
                $('#add').live('click',function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    num = num+1;
                    $('#delete').prop('disabled','');
                    $('#date' + num).datepick({
                    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    yearRange: '1800:2053'
                    });
                    $('#datep' + num).datepick({
                    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    yearRange: '1800:2053'
                    });                    
                    var html = '<div id="input'+num+'" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="alternate">Name '+num+': <input type="text" name="the_name'+num+'" id="name'+num+'" class="textbox" /> From :<input type="text" id="date'+num+'" name="from'+num+'" class="textbox" /> To :<input type="text" id="datep'+num+'" name="to'+num+'" class="textbox" /> Photo: <input type="file" id="photo'+num+'" name="photo'+num+'" class="textbox" /></div>';

                    $('#container').append('<div id="input'+num+'" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="alternate">'+html+'</div>');
                    if (num == 10)
                        $('#add').prop('disabled','disabled');
                });

                $('#delete').click(function() {

                    $('#input' + num).remove();
                    num = num -1;
                    if (num == 1)
                        $('#delete').prop('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#add').prop('disabled','');
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `console.log(num)` in the function you pass to `live()`. I suspect this is a scope issue and `num` is being reset each time so will always equal `1` (and you already have the elements `#date1` and `#datep1` so the date picker will simply be re-attached to those).

Comment: Try moving `num` into the global scope (put it immediately after `<script type="text/javascript">`, before `$(function(){`)

Comment: it is already there? are sure that you read the code?

Comment: Move `var num = 1;` to **before** `$(function(){`, at the moment it's *after* it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var num = 1; 
            $(function(){ ...

still no error no working...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4671/discussion-between-dr-linux-and-clive)

Comment: @Incognito: I haven't had much sleep lately, my brain is just spitting things out :). Maybe it's time for bed...

Comment: sorry this conservation not helped me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of structural problems there, making the document a mess; this makes troubleshooting more difficult.

First things first, get rid of those numerous `$(function() {` blocks - condense your javascript into one block, at the bottom of the page. CSS in the head, javascript includes at the very end of the body, followed by page script.

Your immediate problem is called because when you do this:

```
$('#date' + num).datepick({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: '1800:2053'
});
$('#datep' + num).datepick({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: '1800:2053'
});

var html = '<div id="input'+num+'" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="alternate">Name '+num+': <input type="text" name="the_name'+num+'" id="name'+num+'" class="textbox" /> From :<input type="text" id="date'+num+'" name="from'+num+'" class="textbox" /> To :<input type="text" id="datep'+num+'" name="to'+num+'" class="textbox" /> Photo: <input type="file" id="photo'+num+'" name="photo'+num+'" class="textbox" /></div>';
```

... putting aside the messy long HTML string (use DOM objects to add content to the page), the problem here is that you are calling the `datepick` method on an element that does not yet exist on the page. The big line of HTML creation should go **BEFORE** you try to interact with it.  Thus:

```
var html = '<div id="input'+num+'" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="alternate">Name '+num+': <input type="text" name="the_name'+num+'" id="name'+num+'" class="textbox" /> From :<input type="text" id="date'+num+'" name="from'+num+'" class="textbox" /> To :<input type="text" id="datep'+num+'" name="to'+num+'" class="textbox" /> Photo: <input type="file" id="photo'+num+'" name="photo'+num+'" class="textbox" /></div>';
$('#container').append('<div id="input'+num+'" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="alternate">'+html+'</div>');

$('#date' + num).datepick({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: '1800:2053'
});
$('#datep' + num).datepick({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: '1800:2053'
});
```

Now some homework:

[document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) - Use this instead of big messy HTML strings

[Script position](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) - The article is related to performance, but being organized will help YOUR performance as a developer

[Divitis](http://csscreator.com/divitis) - You've got DIVs coming out the wazoo and this is a pretty short page. Take better advantage of CSS

[Avoid inline styles](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm) - You've got stylesheets attached... use em!

[Use Jquery's document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) - those `$(function() {` things... yuck!

Comment: but nothing changed when i change position of html variable... I think thereis a problem with plug-in... http://pastebin.com/b9HC8sCR

Comment: Make sure you also moved this line above the datepicker attachment: `$('#container').append('<div id="input'+num+'" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="alternate">'+html+'</div>');`... in my original post, I neglected to put that in there, edited to fix.